# AudioStream cannot find file Java

Tags: java, audio, fileinputstream

I am trying to make background music for my game, but when I try to get the file, it brings up the error File Not Found. Here is my code:

```
package TBG;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Sound {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //File here = new File("Slow.wav");
    //System.out.println(here.getAbsolutePath());

 music();
}
public static void music(){

AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
AudioData MD;
ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;

try{
AudioStream BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/GrffinStout/Documents/Eclipse Stuff/G Text RPG/Slow.wav"));
MD = BGM.getData();
loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);
}catch(IOException error){}

MGP.start(loop);
}

}
```

Comment: I used getAbsolutePath() to find the correct file path so the path is correct

Comment: Where should I put the file so that it can be accessed?

Comment: I changed the code in the question in my question and in my real code but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Mac file paths don't use `C:` - that is only for Windows.

On Macs (or any Unix or Linux system) absolute file paths start with `/` so you just want `/Users/GrffinStout/Documents/Eclipse Stuff/G Text RPG/Slow.wav`.